# Error pops when I call a function to use the data I took from a sheet in other macros. Can anyone explain why it says 'object required'?

Tags: excel, vba, object, error-handling, datastore

I want to store data from an excel sheet into arrays and then use them in different macros. I've written the following function to store data then I call it in different macros but an error pops up and says "Object required". Please help me.

```
Public Function data()

Dim i, j, t1, t2 As Integer
Dim x As Range
Dim dt() As Date
Dim price(), bch() As Single
Dim chp(), chb() As Integer


Sheets("Data").Select                        
Range("B8").Select
Set x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range("B8").End(xlDown).Rows.Count 'getting the range


For i = 1 To x                       'stores data into the array
    Cells(i + 8, 1).Value = dt(i - 1)
    Cells(i + 8, 2).Value = price(i - 1)

    Cells(i + 8, 3).Value = bch(i - 1)
    Cells(i + 8, 4).Value = chp(i - 1)
    Cells(i + 8, 5).Value = chb(i - 1)
Next

End Function
```

Comment: Can you specify the line on which you get this error message?

Comment: You can't `Set x = 1` - you should just say `x = 1` (and I suspect you don't really want to just assign 1 to the variable `x` anyway, so you probably want `Row` rather than `Rows.Count`) (and `x` should be a `Long`, not a `Range`)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Which line is generating the error?

Comment: My answer will get you past your current issue, but are the variables `dt`, `price`, etc actually going to have values? Your posted code shows them being locally scoped to the posted code, but your question seems to be implying that they are assigned values in another macro - is it just that you haven't posted the code where you are passing those variables as parameters to the other macros, or are you expecting locally scoped variables in other procedures to have global scope? (That's probably another question if you can't resolve that from the many other questions dealing with that issue.)

Comment: When you declare something as a range, a range is a type of object. Objects are sets of data and functions under a name. Look up object oriented programming to learn more. Whenever you get that error, it's like the type error you get when you try to set a number variable to a string. The variable was set to receive something else.

Comment: dt and price are arrays which will take up data from a sheet. Yeah I haven't just posted the code of other macro. Its just one line "Call data"  over there. I've removed the keyword Set from 'Set x = ActiveSheet.....' still the same line shows error

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a `Range` to be a number.  So the statement

```
Set x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range("B8").End(xlDown).Rows.Count
```

won't work.

---

`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range("B8").End(xlDown)` will be referring to a single cell, so its `Rows.Count` will always return the number 1.

So you are getting an error because you are trying to set `x` (a `Range`) to `1` (a `Long`).

---

Judging by your use of `x` in the `For i = 1 to x` loop, and your use in that loop of `i + 8`, you seem to be trying to find how many rows are being used below row 8 (so, if the last used row was row 10, you seem to want `x` to be `2` so that the loop updates rows 9 and 10), so you really want to use:

```
Dim x As Long
x = ActiveSheet.Range("B8").End(xlDown).Row - 8
```

---

FYI, also be aware that

```
Dim i, j, t1, t2 As Integer
```

is equivalent to

```
Dim i As Variant, j As Variant, t1 As Variant, t2 As Integer
```

not to

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, t1 As Integer, t2 As Integer
```